# Input voltage from supply dropping when connected to an LM317

Tags: lm317

[image]I am having an adapter which can give output of 5V and 1Amp( I have tested it). But when ever I connect this adapter to Vin of an LM317, the input voltage is itself dropping to 2.5V.

Comment: So you are just connecting one wire to a 317 and nothing else to anywhere? So not even a closed circuit of any kind?

Comment: Include the schematic, this is a minimum here.

Comment: There is a circuit. I am using this a current regulator which supplies a constant current to some LEDs. Yeah, it is a closed circuit. I understand if there is a drop in voltage from input to output. But, here input itself is dropping

Comment: "There is a circuit". I guess there is, yeah. But *we* don't have it, and that's my point. Don't even try to describe it with words, it's not clear and detailed enough. We need a picture.

Comment: You have omitted the capacitors recommended by the manufacturer in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf) (for which you failed to provide a link). Do you know something about the device that they don't?

Comment: I haven't connected a heat sink yet.

Comment: Check my answer for how an LM317 current source is supposed to be connected.

Comment: I'm lost. So there was no schematic, then there was (but incorrect), @Michael answered (based on wrong schematic), so OP updated schematic. What's the status now ? Problem still there with circuit as described in *good* schematic ?

Comment: @dim : Yes, problem still exists.

Comment: Ok. Honestly, I don't know why. But I think there is a problem anyway. LM317 needs about 2V voltage drop from input to output to maintain regulation. We also have 1.25V drop due to the resistor and the ADJ pin. with a 5V supply, it leaves 1.75V for the LEDs. I don't know what kind of LED it is, but chances are it's not enough. Well, I don't think it can explain an overcurrent condition. But the circuit is certainly inappropriate for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** Schematic provided.

You have a serious problem of how you have hooked up your current source. Do it like this:

[image]

You have failed to provide the fundamental communications tool for electronics which is a schematic. As such it is not possible to give you any kind of decent answer or suggestions of how to adjust the circuit.

But that said it seems very obvious that when you apply the load to your power supply that that load is demanding more current than your little 5V @ 1A supply is capable of providing. The power source is either current limiting to protect itself OR is grunting with extreme stress and simply being pulled down to the 2.5V. In the latter case I hope the supply does not overheat and fizzle out with a pop and burst of smoke or flame.

Comment: @Micheal Even I was thinking of the same thing. I am planning to give a supply of 5V, 2A now. According to this hypothesis, we should see a less fall in input voltage.

Comment: @Vikas - There might be less fall in input voltage. But maybe not.

Comment: @Vikas - With your schematic as shown the higher capacity supply will have similar problem.

Comment: @Vikas:  You have your LEDs connected to Out on the LM317.  They need to be connected to ADJ.

Comment: @JRE : Sry, I have drawn a wrong circuit. I have updated the picture now.

Comment: @MichaelKaras : Could you please elaborate on the use of capacitor here. I think capacitor only helps in protecting the circuit from voltage fluctuations.

Comment: Capacitor is useful on the input to provide stability - i.e. eliminate any possibility of oscillation occurring due to source impedance interactions with whatever goes on inside the voltage regulator chip. Don't worry - deploy the capacitor, they are very inexpensive.

Comment: @MichaelKaras : sure thing, why do you think that "higher capacity supply will have similar problem of input voltage dropping"

Comment: I say that because you have something not right. Either your load is drawing way more current than you think or your supply is just not up to the job. Since you designed for ~40mA why not use your meter to see how much current your load is actually putting on the supply. Also as another test try putting a 125 ohm load on the supply by itself and see if it can supply 40mA at 5V.